# Latest Jenkins and Artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I attempted to upgrade Jenkins and Artifactory to the latest, and now nothing works.

Specifically, the Artifactory plugin block doesn't show up anymore, after installation.

Versions:

```
jenkins-2.253-1.1.noarch
Artifactory Plugin 3.8.0
Artifactory Open source license 7.7.3 rev
```

When configuring a project, there used to be something like deploy to Artifactory under Post-Build Actions but now there's nothing.

Nothing under (Manage Jenkins > Configure System) relating to Artifactory either.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing works"? Does jenkins start up? Do your pipelines work? Has some plug-ins stopped working? Please specify your question a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Read the rest of the question?  I don't think I can be more clear about what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my advice - read changelogs of jenkins and plugins just before the update and make a backup of main config file at $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml at least.

Which versions of jenkins and plugins were before the update? Let's check changelogs together.

To revert plugin version go to plugin manager in jenkins

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, thanks.  It hasn't been upgraded for 4 years.  So I got the JFrog block back under 'Configure System' after reverting the Artifactory plugin to 3.7.3.  But now I can't get 'Test Connection' to work.  When I configure a task, and try to build, it says, Could not find artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 in internal-repository (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo)   - if I go to that address, it forwards to localhost:8082/ui ... what would the latest 'internal-repository' be, for a fresh Artifactory install? "Custom base URL" is http://servername:8082

Comment: http://server:8082/artifactory/libs-release-local/ does resolve to an empty list though.  So perhaps I just need to work out why it's looking for internal-repository at /artifactory/repo

Comment: Ok sorted.  Had to edit the /usr/local/maven/conf/settings.xml to point 'internal-repository' to the new URL for a virtual repo

Comment: Can't answer the question related to artifactory, last time I was working with it was more than 1 year ago. But in any case please read changelogs first.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, well it shows up after manually installing plugin 3.7.3 instead of 3.8.0

https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/artifactory/

So I guess something broke.  Thanks for the help.